# Windows - jboss on docker, connection refused to local oracle database

Tags: windows, oracle, docker, jboss, connection

I have **Jboss** running in a **docker** container. On jboss I have defined a connection to the xa-datasource database as the ip address of my computer and not localhost because I work in **Windows 10**. Despite the correct ip and port to the database (**oracle**) I keep getting the **connection refused error**. I run jboss with the command

`docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 myjboss`

Can anyone help me, or do I need any additional settings in my docker. I will add that I also test alpine and in the container (`exec`) I can ping my ip address.

Thanks a lot for all the answers. I would like to add that I tested all other solutions contained in similar questions, but unfortunately I did not get the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using not ip/localhost but `host.docker.internal` as described here -> https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/

Answer (score 1):

If you can ping your host IP, but you can’t connect to the database, granted that the DB is running and the listener is up...

I’d advise you to check the `Windows Firewall` settings.

Maybe try disabling it to check if you can actually connect to the database, if so, add an `Inbound Rule` to the firewall to allow connections on port `1521` (or whatever port your listener is running on)

Comment: Thank you a lot, but i found other solution for this problem. It is not problem with firewall